# Attach components to GroupBox in C#

Tags: c#, groupbox

I want to insert a group box in the form and put in 3 radio buttons in it.

Are there any advantages in attaching the 3 radio buttons to the groupbox.? Cab we even do that?

If I have to do it how do i attach the 3 radio buttons to the groupbox so that they become part of the group box and not separate components on the form?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are talking winforms; simply drag the radio button controls into the `GroupBox` in the forms designer. If you want to add them programmatically, something like this should work:

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.Text = "Some text";
myGroupBox.Controls.Add(rb);
rb.Location = new Point(someX, someY);

// repeat as necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

In code, assuming that you have a groupbox variable name groupBox1:

```
groupBox1.Controls.Add(radioButton1);
groupBox1.Controls.Add(radioButton2);
groupBox1.Controls.Add(radioButton3);
```

If you mean in terms of the designer, just drag the radiobuttons on to the groupbox rather than the form.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do it on one line:

```
groupBox1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3 });
```