# how to set a control inside a user control as a container

Tags: c#, user-controls, containers, groupbox

I have user control consisting of a 2 buttons and a groupbox (C#).
When I add controls inside this user control , I want them to be contained inside the groupbox and not the user control itself. Is there a way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too difficult to do really.

```
myGroupBox.Controls.Add(control)
```

Another user left a bit more detailed answer which will probably be of use.
[Attach components to GroupBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410884/attach-components-to-groupbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thats for a normal groupbox  but my groupbox is inside a user control and i want to add it in design mode